# Why doesn't regexp used as an object key match?

Tags: javascript, regex

The code is pretty self-explanatory. Why does it match directly, and not when introduced via `for..in`?

```js
// just for snippet
function print(x) { document.write(x + "<br>\n"); }

var routes = { };
routes[/[0-9]+/] = function(x) { print("number(" + x + ")"); }

function handle(x) { 
    for (var r in routes) {
        print("trying " + r + " on " + x);
        if (x.match(r)) {
            print("hit");
            return routes[r](x);
        }
    }
}

handle("test");
handle("5");

// however
print("5".match(/[0-9]+/));
```

I thought it's because of the fact that `for..in` converts to `String`, but according to [MDN docs on `match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> **regexp**: A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

**EDIT:**
It seems that

```
"5".match("/[0-9]+/")
```

Doesn't work. I guess I'm closer to solving it on my own, but I'll still like external input on the inner mechanics of that.

Comment: "5".match("/[0-9]+/") probaly doesn't work because of the slashes. Either use "5".match("[0-9]+") for implicit conversion or "5".match(/[0-9]+/) for explicit regexp object. However this shouldn't affect your `handle()` method because its correct in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing the RegExp literal, the `/` at the ends are also included as part of the string. That is why they are not matching.

For example,

```
console.log(new RegExp("/[0-9]+/"))
/\/[0-9]+\//
```

As you see in the example shown above, the `/` is also escaped and included as part of the regular expression.

Comment: I've just managed to "fix" that using `r = r.substring(1, r.length-1);` So yeah, that's correct.